# How to wait until iFrame loaded using AppleScript/JavaScript in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, applescript

How to wait until iFrame loaded using AppleScript/JavaScript in Google Chrome?

I tried this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        repeat while (execute javascript "document.readyState;") is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Nothing happend.

And this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "var contentDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument;"
        repeat while (execute javascript "contentDocument.querySelectorAll('a[role=\"button\"]').length > 0 ? 'complete' : 'not complete';") is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Endless cycle. Doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You made such a small mistake: You have to check if `execute javascript "document.readyState;"` `is equal to` or `is not equal to` complete since `document.readyState` returns a string.

So the right solution would be:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        repeat while (execute javascript "document.readyState;") is not equal to "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which webpage you are working with, so try following script yourself. If at some point in time the element you need appears on the page, then the script should return its content in the form of HTML.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window
    repeat while (execute javascript "document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].innerHTML;") is ""
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    set contentDocument to execute javascript "document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].innerHTML;"
end tell
```